# How I can toggle() show/hide next table row when click on any of rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How I can toggle() hide/show next table row contents when I click on any rows? 
I am trying to create expandable table row .

This is my Javascript code:
here i am trying to initially hide all rows have no class="accordion"
then by any click on any rows I need to show next row element (rowContent)

```js
 $(function() {
            var $research = $('.treat-table');
            $research.find("tr").not('.accordion').hide();
            $research.find("tr").eq(0).show();

            $research.find(".accordion").click(function(){
                $(this).next("tr").toggle();
            })
        });
```

```css
table.basic-table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

table.basic-table th {
  background-color: #66676b;
  text-align: left;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: 500;
}

table.basic-table th:first-child {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

table.basic-table th:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

table.basic-table th,
table.basic-table td {
  padding: 15px 28px;
}

table.basic-table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f6f6f6
}

table.basic-table {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<table class="basic-table treat-table">

  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Treatment Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>+</th>
  </tr>
 
  <!-- Row -->
  <tr class="accordion">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Plastic surgery</td>
    <td>Nose job</td>
    <td>from 2000$</td>
    <td>+</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowContent">
    <td colspan="5">
    <h5>This is content</h5>
    <p>This area show hided content</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
 <!-- Row -->
  <tr class="accordion">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Plastic surgery</td>
    <td>Nose job</td>
    <td>from 2000$</td>
    <td>+</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowContent">
    <td colspan="5">
    <h5>This is content</h5>
    <p>This area show hided content</p>
    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

I am trying next() method to select next element and then call toggle() method in my function running onclick of any rows.

Comment: It looks like you're not using your `.research` class anywhere.

Comment: I edit it and add treat-table class to my <table>

Comment: Looks good to me, it's working as expected. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that 2 thing are happening. On the one hand, .research class is not used, and on the other hand, Toggle() does not exist. Check toggle().
Hope it helps.

```js
$(function() {
            var $research = $('.research');
            $research.find("tr").not('.accordion').hide();
            $research.find("tr").eq(0).show();

            $research.find(".accordion").click(function(){
                $(this).next("tr").toggle();
            })
        });
```

```css
table.basic-table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

table.basic-table th {
  background-color: #66676b;
  text-align: left;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: 500;
}

table.basic-table th:first-child {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

table.basic-table th:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

table.basic-table th,
table.basic-table td {
  padding: 15px 28px;
}

table.basic-table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f6f6f6
}

table.basic-table {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<table class="basic-table treat-table research">

  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Treatment Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>+</th>
  </tr>
 
  <!-- Row -->
  <tr class="accordion">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Plastic surgery</td>
    <td>Nose job</td>
    <td>from 2000$</td>
    <td>+</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowContent">
    <td colspan="5">
    <h5>This is content</h5>
    <p>This area show hided content</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I edit it, and change class .research to .treat-table, now please help me because it does not work anyway

Answer (score 0):

Keeping Both `HTML DOM` and `CSS` same, replace your `jQuery` Code with the below `code` Hope it works.

```
$(function() {
    $('.rowContent').hide();
    $(".basic-table .accordion").click(function() {
       (".rowContent").not($(this).next()).hide();
        $(this).next(".rowContent").toggle();
    })
});
```

```js
$(function() {
            $('.rowContent').hide();
            $(".basic-table .accordion").click(function(){
            $(".rowContent").not($(this).next()).hide();
                $(this).next(".rowContent").toggle();
            })
        });
```

```css
table.basic-table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

table.basic-table th {
  background-color: #66676b;
  text-align: left;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: 500;
}

table.basic-table th:first-child {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

table.basic-table th:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

table.basic-table th,
table.basic-table td {
  padding: 15px 28px;
}

table.basic-table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f6f6f6
}

table.basic-table {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<table class="basic-table treat-table">

  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Treatment Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>+</th>
  </tr>
 
  <!-- Row -->
  <tr class="accordion">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Plastic surgery</td>
    <td>Nose job</td>
    <td>from 2000$</td>
    <td>+</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowContent">
    <td colspan="5">
    <h5>This is content</h5>
    <p>This area show hided content</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
 <!-- Row -->
  <tr class="accordion">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Plastic surgery</td>
    <td>Nose job</td>
    <td>from 2000$</td>
    <td>+</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowContent">
    <td colspan="5">
    <h5>This is content</h5>
    <p>This area show hided content</p>
    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Please leave a comment if it doesnot work.